# Game Maker: How to check overlapping instances of the same object?

Tags: collision-detection, game-maker

I want to make sure that no two instances of `obj_A` are overlapping, but can't seem to figure anything out, because `instance_position`, `instance_nearest` and the like will include the instance running it, so if I had something like:

```
if instance_position(x,y,obj_A)!=noone
{
    with(instance_position(x,y,obj_A))
    {
        instance_destroy()
    }
}
```

All instances of obj_A will destroy themselves because they think they are overlapping with themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
with(obj_A){
    if (id!=other.id) and (place_meeting(x,y,other)){
        instance_destroy();
    }
}
```

As it turned out, I just needed to compare the instances' `id`'s.